# Custom Controllers in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I don't know if this is a duplicate, I  couldn't find anything. I'm sorry.

Alright, so I've made a couple of classes like this:

```
abstract class Bank(){}
class HB extends Bank(){}
class NO extends Bank(){}
class BankController(){}
class Contract(){}
```

and I'm using them like this:

```
$contract  = new Contract();
$bank      = new HB();
$bankC     = new BankController($bank);
$bankC->setContract($contract)->processContract()->sendRequest();
```

My question is, where do I put the BankController? Because I don't really wanna put them in the controller folder cause I don't want to access them through the URL.
What would you guys do? Or do you create a new folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a controller function private by starting the name with a underscore.
So for example Contract would be accesible if you placed it in the controller folder but _Contract would not. You will still be able to use it within your controller file itself if you might need that one day.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of OOP.

I don't want the url to be able to call any of this information.

But I want to use it in a different controller.

Comment: @MaggiQall You could create you custom library, if you don't want it to be in a controller folder

Comment: @tomexsans that's what I thought. so what would you call this folder then.? CC?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Custom core controller:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

OR you could create a library if you would not want it on the url:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

on the application/libraries directory create a 
`bank.php`

or you could create a folder like bankfolder/bank.php

```
class bank()
{

  public function setContract()
  {
     //
  }

  public function processContract()
  {
    //
  }

  public function sendRequest()
  {
    //
  }

}
```

then on HB COntroller

```
class HB extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('bankfolder/bank');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->bank->setContract($contract)->processContract()->sendRequest();
  }

}
```

*This is just a sample and not a working code of yours*